# Play Framework Migrate from 2.1.x to 2.3.0 with Deadbolt

Tags: java, playframework-2.2, deadbolt, playframework-2.3

I have a pretty simple application that I want to upgrade from 2.1.x to 2.3.0 with deadbolt. While Deadbolt hasn't officially came out for 2.3.x, the versions for 2.2.x should be good enough (also, this error occurs on 2.2.x).

I have a simple check in a template for if subject is present

```
@subjectPresent() { <p>Hi</p> }
```

Yet I get a compiler error

```
bad symbolic reference. A signature in subjectPresent.class refers to term templates in package play which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling subjectPresent.class.
```

Now, this would seemingly point to some sort of path issue, but I am just unsure of how to go about fixing it.

My build.sbt has the proper resolvers

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Snapshot Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

and declares the dependencies

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
     // .....
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.2.1-RC2"
```

)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a showstopper issue for upgrading to  Play 2.3.0 is currently this: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2/issues/47 . At least in my case. I'd first wait for it to be fixed and released before spending more time on upgrading.

I recommend to properly complete the upgrade to Play 2.2.x for now, so that you know you're not attempting something that's not really possible right now. This upgrade was quite painful for our project and serves as a good checkpoint for you.

EDIT: try now with this new version that was just released and should support Play! 2.3.0:

*"be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.0-RC1"*